# Converting a Weka classifier into a score

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I'm trying to convert my classifier result from classifying instances as 0 or 1, to instead give a score (confidence measure?), say between 0 and 10, 
I am using a RIDOR classifier but could also use ClassificationViaRegression, RandomForest or AttributeSelectedClassifier just as easily, although they don't classify quite as well.

I have output everything I can to the terminal (all the options checked), but I can't find a confidence measure anywhere in the predictions. In addition I understand none of these have the option to output the source code? In which case i'll have to code the classifiers manually.

Here is an example of the rules generated:

```
    class = 2  (40536.0/20268.0)
       Except (fog <= 14.115114) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.973684) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.245) and (Characters/Word > 4.331715) => class = 1  (2309.0/5.0) [1137.0/4.0]
       Except (fog <= 14.115598) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.973684) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence > 1.514706) => class = 1  (2281.0/0.0) [1112.0/0.0]
       Except (fog <= 14.136126) and (Words/Sentence > 19.651515) and (polySyllableCount <= 10.5) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence > 2.416667) and (Syllables/Sentence <= 34.875) => class = 1  (601.0/0.0) [303.0/6.0]
       Except (fog <= 14.140863) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.944444) and (polySyllableCount <= 4.5) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.416667) and (wordCount > 29.5) and (Characters/Word <= 4.83156) => class = 1  (333.0/0.0) [152.0/0.0]
       Except (fog <= 14.142217) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.944444) and (polySyllableCount <= 4.5) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.416667) and (numOfChars > 30.5) and (Syllables/Word <= 1.474937) => class = 1  (322.0/0.0) [174.0/4.0]
       Except (fog <= 14.140863) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.75) and (polySyllableCount <= 4.5) => class = 1  (580.0/28.0) [298.0/21.0]
       Except (fog <= 14.141508) and (Syllables/Sentence > 25.585714) and (Words/Sentence > 19.683333) and (sentenceCount <= 4.5) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 2.291667) and (fog > 12.269468) => class = 1  (434.0/0.0) [202.0/0.0]
       Except (fog <= 14.140863) and (Syllables/Sentence > 25.866071) and (polySyllableCount <= 16.5) and (fog > 12.793102) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 2.9) and (wordCount <= 59.5) and (Words/Sentence > 16.166667) and (Words/Sentence <= 24.75) => class = 1  (291.0/0.0) [166.0/0.0]
       Except (fog <= 14.140863) and (Syllables/Sentence > 25.585714) and (Words/Sentence > 19.630682) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence > 2.656863) and (polySyllableCount <= 16.5) and (fog > 13.560337) and (Words/Sentence <= 21.55) and (numOfChars <= 523) => class = 1  (209.0/0.0) [93.0/2.0]
       Except (fog <= 14.147578) and (Syllables/Word <= 1.649029) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.75) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence > 1.303846) and (polySyllabicWords/Sentence <= 1.422619) and (fog > 9.327132) => class = 1  (183.0/0.0) [64.0/0.0]......
```

I am also unsure what the first line means (40536/20368) - does that just mean classify it as 2, unless one of the following rules apply?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, the first line means the default classification should be (2), unless one of the rules below is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, deriving confidence from classifiers is not regarded as an easy task, especially if you'd like it calibrated (e.g. presented as chances of the classification being correct). However, there are several relatively easy ways of getting rough estimations.

With tree and rule based classifiers, the numbers in parentheses represent the number of correct/incorrect samples included in the bucket. So, for instance, a bucket with (20,2) would mean there were 20 cases where this rule was correct, and 2 where it was incorrect, based on the train data. You could use this ratio as a rough measure of confidence.

When using regression, you can get WEKA to output the actual numeric result of the classifier (rather than just the class), and base a measure of confidence on it.

More generally, following the documentation, you can use the -p option of the commend line (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487247/the-confidence-level-of-each-specific-instance-in-weka/15494272#15494272)). However, I'm not certain how these numbers are calculated.